# Implementing a chat application in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Basically, the app has to support sign up/sign in functionality and allow user to add friends and allow friends to chat.Since, I am just starting? with rails it's a bit overwhelming. How should I go about it

Also, the aim is not an application for production. 
It'll be great if you could link to some working demos of the same.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to checkout http://campfirenow.com/, a chat client written in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning rails there are lots of great resources online. Try googling for a few.

I would suggest Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book - it includes bits of what you want.

Comment: I installed cygwin for RoR but I see different behaviour in cygwin and powershell. Can you help with that? Thanks! More info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070627/seeing-different-gem-lists-in-cygwin-and-powershell

Comment: Sorry I don't use windows for RoR development - ubuntu or mac make things easier!

Answer (score 0):

You would need ofcourse to read tutorials for rails beginners, I recommend the [official rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

For sign up/sign in, you could use the `devise` [gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), and for chat push you could take a look at `private_pub` [gem](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out a tutorial I did on how to achieve the same using `devise` and `private_pub` gem. I believe this should get you started http://goo.gl/l3e8zN