# seeing different gem lists in cygwin and powershell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, powershell, rubygems, cygwin

I used the `gem list` command in powershell and cygwin and both show different gem lists. 
Cygwin shows

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.2.3)
json (1.7.5)
minitest (2.12.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
```

while in powershell I see :

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.4)
minitest (2.5.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
sass (3.2.1)
```

So, the versions of same gem are also different in two.

Why is it so? Also, I was getting problems with `bundle install` while using rails(int both Cygwin and Powershell). Can it be because of this?

How do I ensure consistency in gems? Doesn't installing a gem via Powershell/cygwin make it available to the entire system?

So, I would like to install a fresh copy of gems and Rails which is consistent across Powershell and cygwin. How do I do that?

running `gem environment` in cygwin gives this:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-11-10 patchlevel 327) [i386-cygwin]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-cygwin
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /cygdrive/c/SPB_Data/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

and in windows powershell it gives :

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/SPB_Data/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: `/usr/lib/ruby/` is not the same as `c:/ruby193/lib/ruby` unless you've got something super-weird going on. Looks like you've got parallel installs.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess based on what information you have given, but it sounds like you have a separate version of ruby installed in cygwin and windows.

One easy way to tell what's going on is to do a `ruby -v` and `gem environment` in both shells, which will tell you which ruby version you are using, and what version ruby thinks it's using, and where Rubygems is looking for gems.

To ensure consistency in gems on windows, I would suggest having one ruby installed and using Bundler to maintain your gems through Gemfile. Remove the ruby you installed through cygwin, and ensure the ruby you use is the same one in both environments (try `ruby -v`)

However, I'm not sure why you're getting bundler errors based on the information you've given.

**EDIT AFTER UPDATE**

So you definitely have two different versions of ruby installed, each with their own unique set of gems. You cannot use the windows version in cygwin, so what I would do would be uninstall the cygwin version (use the cygwin setup.exe to do this! If you don't have it, download it again from the cygwin website. You can indicate packages to remove as well as add) and make sure the `/cygdrive/c/ruby193/bin` is in your cygwin path, so that `which ruby` and `which gem` points at this directory.

Comment: I updated the question detail with the `gem environment` information.

Comment: I unsinstalled ruby and related packages from cygwin but now it doesn't recognize `ruby` or `irb` command and I get this error : `C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Ruby193/bin/irb (LoadError)` . So, how do I run ruby interpreter in cygwin now?

Comment: add /cygdrive/c/Ruby193/bin to your path (`export PATH=/cygdrive/c/Ruby193/bin:$PATH` is the temporary solution, see here for permenant: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: If it's in your path in powershell, it will be in your path in cygwin too. You will need to run irb as irb.bat (or do alias irb=irb.bat)